# BioPython AlignIO ValueError says strings must be same length?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, sequence-alignment

Input fasta-format text file:

http://www.jcvi.org/cgi-bin/tigrfams/DownloadFile.cgi?file=/opt/www/www_tmp/tigrfams/fa_alignment_PF00205.txt

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Bio import AlignIO

seq_file = open('/path/to/fa_alignment_PF00205.txt')
alignment = AlignIO.read(seq_file, "fasta")
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Sequences must all be the same length
```

The input sequences shouldn't have to be the same length since on ClustalOmega you can align sequences of differing lengths.

This also doesn't work...gets the same error:

```
alignment = AlignIO.parse(seq_file,"fasta")

for record in alignment:
    print(record.id)
```

**Does anybody who is familiar with BioPython know how to get around this to align sequences from fasta files?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pad the sequence that is too short and write the records to to a temporary FASTA file. Than your alignments works as expected:

```
from Bio import AlignIO
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import Seq
import os

input_file = '/path/to/fa_alignment_PF00205.txt'
records = SeqIO.parse(input_file, 'fasta')
records = list(records) # make a copy, otherwise our generator
                        # is exhausted after calculating maxlen
maxlen = max(len(record.seq) for record in records)

# pad sequences so that they all have the same length
for record in records:
    if len(record.seq) != maxlen:
        sequence = str(record.seq).ljust(maxlen, '.')
        record.seq = Seq.Seq(sequence)
assert all(len(record.seq) == maxlen for record in records)

# write to temporary file and do alignment
output_file = '{}_padded.fasta'.format(os.path.splitext(input_file)[0])
with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
    SeqIO.write(records, f, 'fasta')
alignment = AlignIO.read(output_file, "fasta")
print alignment
```

This outputs:

```
SingleLetterAlphabet() alignment with 104 rows and 275 columns
TKAAIELIADHQ.......LTVLADLLVHRLQ..AVKELEALLA...QAL SP|A2VGF0.1/208-339
LQELASVINQHE...KV..MLFCGHGCR...Y..AVEEVMALAK...EDL SP|A3D4X6.1/190-319
IKKIAQAIEKAK...KP..VICAGGGVINS.N..ASEELLTLSR...KEL SP|A3DID9.1/192-327
IDEAAEAINKAE...RP..VILAGGGVSIA.G..ANKELFEFAT...QLL SP|A3DIY4.1/192-327
IEKAIELINSSQ...RP..FICSGGGVISS.E..ASEELIQFAE...KIL SP|A4XHS0.1/191-326
IKRAVEAIENSQ...RP..VICSGGGVIAS.R..ASDELKILVE...SEI SP|A4XIL5.1/194-328
VRQAARIIMESE...RP..VIYAGGGVRIS.G..AAPELLELSE...RAL SP|A5D4V9.1/192-327
LQALAQRILRAQ...RP..VIITGDEIVKS.D..ALQAAADFAS...LQL SP|A5ECG1.1/192-328
VEKAVELLWSAR...RV..LVISGRGAR...G..AGPELIGLLD...RAM SP|A5EDH4.1/198-324
IQKAARLIETAE...KP..VIIAGHGVNIS.G..ANEELKTLAE...KSL SP|A5FR34.1/193-328
LDALARDLDSAA...RV..TIYAGIGAR...G..AAARVVQLAG...EAL SP|A5FTR0.1/189-317
VADVAALLRAAR...RP..VIVAGGGVIHSG...AEERLATFAA...DAL SP|A5G0X6.1/217-351
IAEAVSALKGAK...RP..IIYTGGGLINS.GPESAELIVQLAK...RAL SP|A5G2E1.1/199-336
LKKAAEIINRAK...RP..LIYAGGGITLA.G..ASAELRALAA...ALL SP|A5GC69.1/192-327
CRDIVGKLLQSH...RP..VVLGGTGVRLS.R..TEQRLLALVE...DVF SP|A5W0I1.1/200-336
LDQAALKLAAAE...RP..MIIAGGGA..L.H..AAEQLAQLSA...AGL SP|A5W220.1/196-326
LQRAADILNTGH...KV..AILVGAGAL...Q..ATEQVIAIAE...RAL SP|A5W364.1/198-328
IRKAAEMLLAAK...RP..VVYSGGGVILG.G..GSEALTEIAK...SEM SP|A5W954.1/196-331
...
LTELQERLANAQ...RP..VVILGGSRWSD.A..AVQQFTRFAE...... SP|Q220C3.1/190-328
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is last record of fasta ... `tail -9 fa_alignment_PF00205.txt`

```
>SP|Q21VK8.1/229-357
LQAALAALAKAE...RP..LLVIGSQALVLSK..QAEHLAEAVARL.GIPV.YLSGMA..RGLLG.R..........DH.
...............PLQ..................MRHQRRQALRE..ADCVLLAG.VP...CDFRLD......YGKHV
RR..............S.AT.........L..IAA.N......................RSA.........KDARLNR..
.......K...PD.IAAIGDAG.......LFLQAL
>SP|Q220C3.1/190-328
LTELQERLANAQ...RP..VVILGGSRWSD.A..AVQQFTRFAEAF.SLPV.FCSFRR..QMLFS.A..........NH.
...............ACY...AG.DLGLG.A.....NQRLLARI.RQ..SDLILLLG.GR...MSEVPS......QGYEL
LGIPAPQQ...........D
```

Sequence with id `SP|Q220C3.1/190-328` has different length than other sequences