# How to trim or pad a sequence to be a certain length bio python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

Whats the easiest way to trim or pad a group of biopython fastfa files untill they are all a certain length so that I can add them to a multiple sequence alignment? [BioPython AlignIO ValueError says strings must be same length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833230/biopython-alignio-valueerror-says-strings-must-be-same-length) Similar to the answer here except with multiple sequences, no text file and in the end it should all be incorporated into a multiplesequenceallignment. The end goal is to have all sequences be 570 characters. I intend to incoporate all of this into a phylum tree

Comment: Do you have an example and a desired result that can help us to understand your need ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833230/biopython-alignio-valueerror-says-strings-must-be-same-length Something like the answer to this except I need it done too multiple sequences and I don't know if the sequence is too short or too long. Also I just use fastfas instead of text files.

Comment: rather than trimming/padding your sequences, shouldn't you be aligning them? `Bio.AlignIO` is for manipulating sequences that are already aligned and if you want to build a phylogeny, it is based on the alignment with gaps appropriately placed not arbitrary padding

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Biopython, but I know you easily do in [pysam](https://onestopdataanalysis.com/fastq-to-fasta/) by reading the FASTA, looping over each sequence, trim the sequence to a certain size, and then writing it to a new FASTA. See example below:

```
from pysam import FastxFile


fasta_q_file = "INPUT.fasta"
out_filename = "OUTPUT_NAME.fasta"
size_size_trim = 50


with FastxFile(fasta_q_file) as fh, open(out_filename, mode='w') as fout:
    for entry in fh:
        sequence_id = entry.name
        sequence = entry.sequence

        if sequence > size_size_trim:
            fout.write(">{}_trimmed_to_{}_bp\n{}\n".format(size_size_trim,sequence_id, sequence[:size_size_trim]))

        else:
            if sequence == size_size_trim:
                fout.write(">{}\n{}\n".format(sequence_id, sequence[:size_size_trim]))
            else:
                # sequences shorter than `size_size_trim` are not written.
                continue
```